# How do I monitor my CPU and RAM usage without installing any software?

Tags: ram, cpu

I want to monitor my CPU and RAM usage without installing any software.

This is just an example, it is not real:

CPU:42%
RAM:100%

I am trying to do this on Ubuntu 20.04.3
Doing this to see if any are bottleneck.

Please tell me if I need to provide more info.

Comment: You can use the "contents" of the `stat` and `meminfo` "pseudofiles" under the `/proc` filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the `top` command and `free` in the terminal without installing additional software.

The `top` command allows you to monitor the most active processes, updating the display at regular intervals.

The `free` command in terminal displays memory usage in Kb.

see these references:

[how to use top](https://www.lifewire.com/linux-top-command-2201163)

[how to use free](https://www.howtogeek.com/456943/how-to-use-the-free-command-on-linux/)

[man page for top](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html)

[man page free](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/free.1.html)