# How can I understand the reason my computer freezes?

Tags: hardware, ram, cpu

I would like to ask a question:
Due to my job I often use many programs together and sometimes my computer freezes, sometimes I can really feel its pain.
This often happens when I both use Skype (video calls) and IntelliJ or Virtual Machine is on.

How can I understand if this is due by CPU or RAM (or maybe something else)?

Thank you for your help.

EDIT.
As suggested by @heynnema, here is the result for commands `free -h`

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          5,8Gi       4,2Gi       327Mi        67Mi       1,2Gi       1,2Gi
Swap:         2,0Gi       679Mi       1,3Gi
```

and `swapon -s`

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/swapfile               file        2097148 695552  -2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I monitor my CPU and RAM usage without installing any software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1369355/how-do-i-monitor-my-cpu-and-ram-usage-without-installing-any-software)

Comment: That definetly helps but the thing is in this way I must stare at the terminal while I'm using other software.
It would be helpful to have a sort of graph so I can see what was happening while I was working

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `swapon -s`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: When you provide requested data, you have to let the requestor know by sending a comment to them that starts with @heynnema (in my case). `Stacer` is not the answer. Use the standard `System Monitor` app instead. Or use `top`. Let me know if you're still freezing, and I can put together an answer for you.

Comment: What flavor/version of Ubuntu are you running? Show me `sysctl vm.swappiness`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It would be helpful to have a sort of graph so I can see what was
> happening while I was working

Then use ``Stacer` downloadable from the ubuntu software center

[image]

[image]

Comment: This helps. Thank you very much

Comment: nice proggy, shows disk writes and reads too.

Answer (score 1):

Your /swapfile is probably too small. Let's increase it from 2G to 4G...

**Note**: Depending on your usage pattern, you may need more RAM.

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `rm` and `dd` commands can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 6G RAM and 4G swap
```

Edit /etc/fstab, using `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`.

Confirm this /swapfile line in /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines... use SPACES in this line... confirm NO TABS...

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```